# How to improve my English?

Tags: learning

I believe I am a learner with high intermediate level of English and now encounter obstacles in learning English. What I did to improve English when I started learning English, such as reading articles and listening to radio, do not help me much because I am no longer a novice in learning English. I do not know how to further improve my English except trying to learn some new words. Can anyone provide me with some guidance on how to improve my English? I also would like to know how native English speakers improve their mother language!

Answer (score 0):

It is rather simple, basic training devices have done their job; what simple articles and radio have done at a beginner's level, articles in magazines with higher intellectual objectives, such as for instance *National Geographic* (there are others), and works of serious literature will do painlessly for you at this new higher level, while at the same time you will widen  your general understanding of life and the world. There is no better way (I believe); a good command of a language goes hand in hand with a knowledge of the culture that fosters it and culture in general.

<sub>Note: If you don't know what is serious literature get yourself an anthology of literature; that will be a guide for you.</sub>